# std::make_unique<T[]>(size) value-initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Does

```
std::make_unique<double[]>(1000)
```

*allways* value-initialize the elements? Well, I looked into the implementation and `clang` as well as `g++` are using

```
new T[size]()
```

doing value-initialization.

But I can't find that a conforming implementation of C++14 / 17 *has* to do this.

Answer (score 8):

If the standard library is conforming to C++14 then yes it *has* to do this (use `new T[size]`). From C++14 §20.8.1.4[unique.ptr.create]/4:

> `template <class T> unique_ptr<T> make_unique(size_t n);`
>
> - *Returns*: `unique_ptr<T>(new remove_extent_t<T>[n]())`.